# rewrite pretty urls with php and htaccess, mapping 404 for subpages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In .htaccess I have following rules for having page/subpage rewrite.

```
#Permalinks
RewriteEngine on
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#catch potential subpages first
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)/([a-z\-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2 [L]
#
RewriteRule ^([a-z\-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

In php I do this:

```
if (!$_GET) {
    //
    $page = "home";
    $page_title = "General Site Title";
    include ("template/index.php");
    //
} else if ($_GET['page'] == "words") {
    //
    $page = "words";
    $page_title = "Words Page";
    include ("template/words.php");
    //
} else if ($_GET['page'] == "about") {
    //
    $page = "about";
    $page_title = "About Page";
    include ("template/about.php");
    //
} else {
    //
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    //
        include ("template/404.php");
    //
    exit();
    //
}
```

This works great, for showing 404.php when page doesn't exist.

But what if I want to have 404.php also when page/subpage doesn't exist?

For example I'm planning to have /members page. If someone goes to non existing /members/user1, I need to check DB for existing user, if doesn't exist I should show 404.php but is this correct logic to use in this situation?

p.s. how do I add rewrite /about/ to show same page? currently /about returns 200, but /about/ returns apache page not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of correction in rules to make trailing slash optional in both rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/([a-z-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Now about checking `/members/user1` yes you can check DB for existence of member record and if not found you can return 404 status/page.

Comment: `L - Last Rule, QSA - Query String Append, NC - Ignore Case` Reference: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html